# Failed upgrade- what to do?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, bug-reporting

I have just tried to upgrade to U14.04.05LTS and received the following error message:

"Please report this bug for the 'update-manager' package and try to include the following error message:

"'E:Encountered a section with no Package: header, E:Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-security_restricted_binary-i386_Packages, E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.'"

Comment: You will see a solution quicker by asking Launchpad to update you when a fix is at hand. As time permits, may I kindly beg your indulgence in reporting this at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu?field.searchtext=update-manager  ?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you change the [default repositories](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) aka "Software Sources", to a repository closer to you with more bandwidth, and retry it, preferably at a low-traffic time of day.

One method is to go through the "Ubuntu Software Center". Open the software center, then from the Edit menu select "Software Sources". Note: You will have to enter your password to change settings in this window.

Running this command will show you the four fastest for you:

```
sudo netselect -v -s4 -t10 `wget -q -O- https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors | grep -P -B8 "statusUP|statusSIX" | grep -o -P "(f|ht)tp.*\"" | tr '"\n' ' '`
```

However, may I be so bold as to note 14.04.5 will reach [end of life in April](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)? You may wish to consider 16.04 or 18.04 if long term usability is a concern.